# How to create angular 4 project

Tags: angular

I want to create an Angular 4 project but i have tried using

```
ng new myProject --ng4
```

This does not help since the project is created in angular 7. I also tried installing an older version of angular CLI but I was stuck there too.
Is there any way to create an Angular 4 project without degrading my cli version? If there isn't which angular cli will I need to install to create an Angular 4 project. It would be very helpful if I could get the exact version.
Please don't give any answers without trying them on your machine first and confirming that the project created is of Angular 4 and not of any other version.

This is my current ng version

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 8.14.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.1.4
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/core              7.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.4
@ngtools/webpack                  7.1.4
@schematics/angular               7.1.4
@schematics/update                0.11.4
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.23.1
```

Comment: try this https://github.com/Plum-Crazy/angular-seed

Comment: `Is there any way to create an Angular 4 project without degrading my cli version` <= No, you can't use the `angular cli` to create an angular project that is not the same as the supported `angular cli` version. You could install a new *local* `angular cli` of whatever desired version (like 4) and use that to create a new angular project. But in the same project the angular libraries should be the same as the cli library *or* don't use the cli and create the project manually.

Comment: What is the reason you want to create a project in that version? Can't you start a project in Angular 7?

Comment: I just want to see if this can be done or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer. I just have to install the proper CLI version.

angular-cli@0.1.0 - Angular 2

@angular/cli@1.1.0 - Angular 4.0.0

@angular/cli@1.4.10 - Angular 4.2.4

@angular/cli@1.5.0 - Angular 4.4

@angular/cli@1.7.4 - Angular 5.2.0

@angular/cli@6.2.8 - Angular 6.1.0